# Using ?. operator with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) I can use `A?.B?.Do(C);`.

I have a `List` and I want to filter that and then using the `Min` method:

```
var Min = MyList.Where(o => o.Propery1 == 1)?.Min(o => o.Price)
```

The problem is `MyList.Where(o => o.Propery1 == 1)` doesn't return any result and I got this error:

> Sequence contains no elements

And `StackTrace`:

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Min(IEnumerable1 source)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Min[TSource](IEnumerable1 source, Func`2 selector) ...

So what is the problem? Why can't I use the `Min` method with empty list?

Comment: How does your question is related to `?.` operator usage?

Comment: See DefaultIfEmpty https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: LINQ doesn't return `null` for queries, using `Where()?` is hence pointless

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I wonder why you ask this question. If I user normal `.` with `Min` it is normal to get `error` and I add `?.` and I expect that I don't get error

Comment: How about doing the predicate in the Min, rather than the Where (don't have a where clause at all) `var mn = MyList.Min(o => o.Propery == 1 ? (int?)o.Price : null)` .. note, you need to cast the o.Price to the nullable version of whatever it is for this to work out.. Min will throw "sequence contains no elements" if you do it with a value type on a empty list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [`.DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=netcore-3.1) method before calling the `min` method:

```
MyList.Where(o => o.Propery1 == 1).DefaultIfEmpty().Min(o => o?.Price)
```

> The `DefaultIfEmpty`, Returns the elements of an `IEnumerable<T>`, or a default valued singleton collection if the sequence is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The `?.` a.k.a. null conditional operator works when the expression on the left side is null. In this case, you don't have null but an empty enumerable, so, .Max() has no idea what to do when the input is empty.

You have an empty room: return the age of the oldest person

Comment: *Max() has no idea what to do when the input is empty* .. mmmm, it's not quite true. Max knows exactly what to do when the input is empty: for a sequence of value types, throw. For a sequence of ref types, return default